# Problem while Merging Image with Button

Tags: html

Guys check this out : http://www.codetoad.com/html/buttons/image_submit_button.asp

You'll notice then when you click the button it is taking you to

http://www.codetoad.com/html/buttons/image_submit_button.asp?x=118&y=22

How do i remove this "x=118&y=22" at the end.Because my form is a get form and because of this its altering my code..

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the standard behaviour of `<input type="image" />` elements and I don't think you can change it.

You could instead use the `<button>` tag:

```
<button type="submit">
  <img src="someimage.jpg" />
</button>
```

**Edit:** If you don't want it to look like a button, you can use CSS to remove the button styling:

```
button {
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thats adds an image to the button it doesn't change the button itself !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the behaviour and insead of fighting with this behaviour what you can do is apply css on input type=submit. with background-image property.

```
< input type=submit id='submitButton' value='submit' />


<style>
#submitButton {
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 55px 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent url(pathtoyourimage/image.gif) no-repeat center top;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer; /* hand-shaped cursor */
  cursor: hand; /* for IE 5.x */
}
</style>
```

Comment: i have modified my response for further details u asked for.